# Getting IndexOutofBoundsException, unable to figure out why

Tags: java

I'm getting index out of bounds exception and unable to figure out the reason, please help me. I'm trying to iterate through list. List size is 2. I'm trying to create dynamic table and print the list.

```
 public void display(ArrayList list) {

            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

            for(int i = 0;i<=list.size(); i++){

                EmployeeBean empList = (EmployeeBean) list.get(i);

                int count = 0;

                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                tr.setId(100+count);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tr.setClickable(true);

                final TextView empName = new TextView(this);
                empName.setId(200+count);
                empName.setText(empList.getName());
                tr.addView(empName);

                final TextView empStream = new TextView(this);
                empStream.setId(200+count);
                empStream.setText(empList.getStream());
                tr.addView(empStream);

                final TextView empLevel = new TextView(this);
                empLevel.setId(200+count);
                empStream.setText(empList.getLevel());

                final TextView empDesignation = new TextView(this);
                empDesignation.setId(200+count);
                empDesignation.setText(empList.getDesignation());

                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               count++;

               tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        outpuText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        outpuText.setText("Name: " + empName.getText() + "\n"
                                + "Stream: " + empStream.getText() + "\n" + "Level: "
                                + empLevel + "\n" + "Designation :" + empDesignation);
                        setContentView(outpuText);

                    }
                });

            }
```

The exception which I'm receiving is

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
```

Comment: 6 answers all pointing out same thing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0;i<=list.size(); i++)
```

index starts from ZERO and [size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29) Returns the number of elements in this list. If you use <=, i value would exceed the number of elements in list which results `IndexOutofBoundsException`,

so above code should be

```
for(int i = 0;i< list.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.size() - 1` instead of `list.size()` in your for loop :

```
for(int i = 0;i<=(list.size() - 1); i++)
```

Or change the `<=` to `<` like:

```
for(int i = 0;i<list.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i<=list.size(); i++)
```

Change it to

```
int size = list.size();
for(int i = 0;i<size; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` starts at zero, and `size()` will return the count of objects in the array, your `for` loop should be modified to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

indices start at 0, and you're testing for list size being 'less than or equal to'

which will return true for three iterations (0,1,2)

changing your 'for' statement to

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void display(ArrayList list) {

         TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

         for(int i = 0;i<=list.size(); i++){
```

it shows here that you are initializating the variable to 0 and in condition you placed <=
replace the condition with < or replace the initialization with 1. it wil work fine Thanks.